# How to notify UITableView on data download complete from AppDelegate when NSNotification is not an option

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method in `AppDelegate` which get some data from server, this method get called every time when application become active. I want to reload some table in another view when server data received successfully. How can i do this without using `NSNotification`?. I know passing notification can do this job. I want to know is there any other way to perform this?

Comment: keep a reference to that view in your appdelegate and call a method on it to reload the table

Comment: Assuming that the data you are loading is being stored in a variable somewhere you can use KVO http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

Comment: Please don't do what Fonix suggests. KVO could work. NSNotificationCenter is probably the right way to do this though - why don't you want to use it? Actually, probably having some other class handle the request entirely is better.

Comment: +1 for `NSNotificationCenter`it is what you probably need.

Comment: And if you use notifications, you on't even have to post them, just listen for this radiostation:     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note){
                                                  }];

Comment: Why are you loading data from server in your app delegate? There are notifications for app becoming active that you should implement in your table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

well comments by users already explained what to do.

But i had another approach.I don't prefer, but it will work.

Always set some constant tag value to your table view (say 1001).And make sure than you never use the same tag on others.

Then in that method of appDelegate, you can do->

```
UITableView *tableView =(UITableView*)[self.window viewWithTag:1001];
[tableView reloadData];
```

I am reminding you again, don't use this. use `NSNotification` class.

Answer (score 0):

Although it creates an unneeded dependency between the view and the app delegate, I'd implement this way:

1. create a `ViewReloader` protocol with a method `- (void) reloadTable;`
2. implement that protocol in the view
3. add a property of type `id<ViewReloader>` to the app delegate
4. when the view is instantiated, assign it to the property defined above
5. when you need to reload, call the `reloadTable` method of the `id<ViewReloader>` property from the app delegate (but always check for property != nil)
6. if the view is destroyed/deallocated, remember to reset the app delegate property

Answer (score 0):

Well samething you can do with using custom delegates as well. If you want to pass message from one object to another. You can use notification also, but use only when you want to broadcast the message.